# How to store the latitude and longitude in mysqli database

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-maps, mysqli

I want to store the latitude and longitude values from this javascript code

```
function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(26.329086,50.227570);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom:12,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap"), myOptions);
    // marker refers to a global variable
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map
    });
    // if center changed then update lat and lon document objects
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function () {
        var location = map.getCenter();
         document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML = location.lat();
        var lon = document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("lon").innerHTML = location.lng();


        // call function to reposition marker location
        placeMarker(location);
    });
    // if zoom changed, then update document object with new info
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
        zoomLevel = map.getZoom();
        document.getElementById("zoom_level").innerHTML = zoomLevel;
    });
    // double click on the marker changes zoom level
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dblclick', function () {
        zoomLevel = map.getZoom() + 1;
        if (zoomLevel == 20) {
            zoomLevel = 10;
        }
        document.getElementById("zoom_level").innerHTML = zoomLevel;
        map.setZoom(zoomLevel);
    });

    function placeMarker(location) {
        var clickedLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(location);
        marker.setPosition(location);
    }
}
window.onload = function () { initialize() };
```

and the values are displayed in the html code through span

```
<div id="gmap">
<span id="lat"></span>
<span id="lon"></span>
```

the values are dynamically change when the user move the marker on the map and i want to pass them to a php code that inserts them in the database.

Comment: Have you tried to send these data via POST to your PHP code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax/jquery to get the information from the span and send the data to your server to save (note you can do it in pure JavaScript but requires a lot more code, your other option is to use a `<form>...</form>` submit method).

Code brief (untested):

(an on click or timeout function )

```
var formdata="lat="+$('#lat').text()+'&lon='+$('#lon').text();

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'save_location.php',
  data: formdata,
  async: false,
}).done(function(data) {
   alert(data)
});
```

Hope this helps to get you started.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but do you mean using $("submit").click(function(){} or put the code in a function and the onClick in the <button> tag, and how is translated to in the php file is it inside $_POST['lat'].

Comment: Both methods will work, depends on what you want to do:
1) If you want to track the locations continually then use a setTimeout function that repeats itself every few seconds and send the data to the server... 2) or you can do the ajax call on a mouse move... 3) mouse click, etc... Just search this forum all the answere are there.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you have got your answer partially. And you have asked , "how I can handle the request inside server by **$_POST** or **$_GET**"
 var formdata="lat="+$('#lat').text()+'&lon='+$('#lon').text();

I will share above code to fulfill your answer. if your form have and id attribute **target_form** then use below code

```
 $( "#target_form" ).submit(function( ) {
     $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'save_location.php',
          data: formdata, //we are passing lat and lon to server
          async: false,
        }).done(function(data) {
           alert(data)
        });
  });
```

So go to your save_location.php file and check it by isset function to skip unwanted errors like

```
if(isset($_POST['lat'])){
  $lat = $_POST['lat'];
  $lat = $_POST['lat'];

  //and save it to server by **mysqli**  or **pdo**
  echo "success";
}
```

Comment: it is still not set, it displays a Undefined variable error to $lat.

Answer (score -1):

SO you can use

```
$( "#target_form" ).submit(function( ) {
    var lat = "7847.343"; //garbage data
    var lon = "85.125"; //garbage data

     $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'save_location.php',
          data: {
               "lat": lat,
               "lon": lon
            } //we are passing lat and lon to server
          async: false,
        }).done(function(data) {
           alert(data)
        });
  });
```